# are nlm() or optimize() more precise than optim() in R

Tags: r, precision

I am trying to get more precise (up to 6 decimal places) estimates of `x[1]` and `x[2]` in my function called `GGG`.

Using `optim`, I get some precision up to 3 decimal places, but am wondering how I can improve precision up to at least 6 decimal places?

Can `optimize` and `nlm` be used for this goal?

```
GGG = function(Low, High, p1, p2) {


f <- function(x) {

 y <- c(Low, High) - qcauchy(c(p1, p2), location=x[1],  scale=x[2]) 

 }


## SOLVE:  
AA <- optim(c(1,1), function(x) sum(f(x)^2) )  

## return parameters:
parms = unname(AA$par)   


return(parms)     ## Correct but up to 3 decimal places 

}

 ## TEST:
 AAA <- GGG (Low = -3, High = 3, p1 = .025, p2 = .975)


 ## CHECK:
 q <- qcauchy( c(.025, .975), AAA[1], AAA[2] ) # What comes out of "q" MUST match "Low" and 
                                               # "High" up to 6 decimal places
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optim function has a tolerance control parameter.  Replace your optim function with this:

```
AA <- optim(c(1,1), function(x) sum(f(x)^2), control=list(reltol=(.Machine$double.eps)))
```

Returns:

```
> q
[1] -3  3
> AAA
[1] 5.956798e-08 2.361051e-01
```